# Maven shade plugin remove "original"

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

Each time I run maven package to produce an updated jar, it creates an "original" jar file, as well as the updated one.

This is particularly an issue for me due to the fact that I'm running the compiled jar automatically, and they're both trying to start.

All I want created is the ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded.jar file produced, and not the "original" one. Is there a way to have it just overwrite without making a backup (I'm assuming that's what it's doing)?

How can I solve this?

Here is my pom:

```
<groupId>com.spiromarshes</groupId>
<artifactId>LiveDebugTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>LiveDebugTest</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <outputDirectory>${dir}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How are you starting your created jar file? It sounds that selects the wrong one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved by using `<outputFile>${dir}/${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>` under the configuration section for maven-shade-plugin.

---

Full example, for context:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <outputFile>${dir}/${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <artifact>*:*</artifact>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </filter>
      </filters>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This does prevent the original from existing, but the final file is the non-shaded one.

Answer (score 4):

The original Maven intended file name for the package includes the version number.
There is a shade-plugin configuration that not only prevents the "original"-prefixed file name, but also achieves the original Maven package name.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        ..                          ..
                        .. more shade configuration ..
                        ..                          ..
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```