# Why does IntelliJ build a regular jar file and an original jar file? Is there any way to remove this feature?

Tags: java, maven

IntelliJ will generate two JAR files, one having the name of my plugin with the version, the other having the name and version but with `original` slapped onto the first part. This plugin has no Git repository, so why does it do this?

I expected one JAR file to appear when building (with Maven) but two appear.

Comment: The "-original" JAR is the unshaded JAR. It does not include dependencies. Please see the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for more info.

Comment: Could be related to: [_Maven shade plugin remove "original"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919125/maven-shade-plugin-remove-original)

Comment: If this is Maven that's generating both JAR files, then IntelliJ has nothing to do with it (even if you're using IntelliJ to delegate to Maven tasks, it's still Maven that's responsible for the output).